# What am I doing wrong to get an array from firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this function in WorkoutController.js

```
export async function getFavourites(FavRetrived) {
    var FavList = []
    var snapshot = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("Favourites")
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection("userFavourites")
        .get()
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const favDoc = doc.data()
        favDoc.id = doc.id
        FavList.push(favDoc)
    })
    FavRetrived(FavList)
}
```

I used basically flatlists to get the datas from the collection and it works good but now I want to use the id's array to do some controls.

I think the second part of the code it creates an array of id but I don't know how to use it or show it.

in Screen.js I have

```
import { getFavourites } from '../context/WorkoutController'
const [FavList, setFavList] = useState()

 useEffect(() => {
  
    getDataFav()
  }, [])

    function getDataFav() {
    getFavourites(FavRetrieved)
    }

    function FavRetrieved(FavList) {
    setFavList(FavList)
    }
```

Like this if I use a flatlist passing FavList as data I can see all the elements of the collection, but what if I want to show just the first id of the array?
I don't want to use where function, I need to see the datas as an array, for example something like FavList[0].name (but this doesn't work)

Comment: You should use the `where` statement in firebase because `.doc()` works only with firebase  default id.

Answer (score 1):

First, we need to tweak `getFavourites` so that it handles the case where the user isn't logged in with a meaningful error and it shouldn't use callbacks if you are making use of `async`/`await` syntax - just use Promise chaining instead.

```
export async function getFavourites() {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (!user)
        return Promise.reject(new Error("User must be signed in first"));

    const favList = []
    const snapshot = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("Favourites")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection("userFavourites")
        .get()

    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const favDocData = doc.data()
        favDocData.id = doc.id
        favList.push(favDocData)
    })

    return favList
}
```

You would then use it in your component like so:

```
import { getFavourites } from '../context/WorkoutController'

// status of favList
const [status, setStatus] = useState("loading")
// array of favourites
const [favList, setFavList] = useState()
// error message to show user
const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState("")

useEffect(() => { 
    let disposed = false

    getFavourites()
        .then((newFavList) => {
            if (disposed) return // component discarded, do nothing.

            setFavList(newFavList)
            setErrorMsg("")
            setStatus("fetched")
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            if (disposed) return // component discarded, do nothing.

            console.error("getFavourites failed: ", err)
            setErrorMsg("Failed to get favourites")
            setStatus("error")
        });

    // return cleanup function
    return () => disposed = true
}, []);

if (status === "loading")
  return (<Spinner />)

if (status === "error")
  return (<div key="error">{errorMsg}</div>)

// if here, favList is now an array of favourite documents data
return ( /* ... render favList ... */ )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function getFavourites(FavRetrived) {
    var FavList = []
    var snapshot = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("Favourites")
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection("userFavourites")
        .get()
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const favDoc = doc.data();
        const id = doc.id;
        FavList.push({ id, ...favDoc })
    })
    FavRetrived(FavList)
}
```

You can access it by `FavList[0].id`